# Assign object members to context menu command - TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I need to replace string in JSON to functions (object methods) with the corresponding name and pass an argument to it
but got

```
"Type 'this[Extract<keyof this, string>]' is not assignable to type '(event?: any) => void'"
```

In short, would like to have something like:

```js
if (typeof this[key] === 'function') {
    position.command = this[key];
}
```

But my solution does not let me pass arguments to it

Comment: Can you show more code. On which object you want to do this.

Comment: just using it for now on this... for (const key in this) { .... } and as you can see it is not assignable to type '(event?: any) => void'" how to cast into it - i've tried <(event?: any) => void><unknown>this[key]; but it does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Also note that this is dangerous since every function will be assigned to command on this.

```
  id = 1;
  name = 'alice';

  position = {
    command: null
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    for (const key in this) {
      console.log(key);

      if (typeof this[key] === 'function') {
          this.position.command = this[key];
      }
    }
  }

  someFunction() {
    console.log('someFunction');
  }
```

See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y9ebx5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) it doesn't give any error.

Error is only there if you initialize command with a string; eg. `command: ''`

Comment: It is exactly how I had tried but please see the error message. This is not the expected type. Our solution does not work because primengy needs to get special lambda type. It doesn't compile at all.

Comment: I updated my answer. Feel free to fork my stackblitz to your use case.

Comment: robert  - your code is simple case and I was aware of it and it is not a rel question. Try to bind such method to field that is defined in interface as  "command: (event?: any) => void"

Comment: @MichałBrzeziński Have you tried "this.position.command = <any>this[key];"

Comment: Hi Robert! That looks very nice - Thanks for your time! I had to skip the issue but will get back soon so will let you know if it works fine for Primengy component. Seems it should work fine for binding. However as mentioned in first question I will have soon another related problem - "how to pass argument to it?". function declaration have argument with element that context menu is prepared for. In declaration takes position but how to pass it in invocation? it looks strange but in PHP will work something like $this[key](argument);